# React checkbox control

Tags: reactjs

I have multiple component and each component has a checkbox.When ı click any checkbox just first one triggered. Other checkboxes isn't selected. How can solve this problem ?

TodoItem component is here :

```js
function TodoItem() {
  
  return (
    <li className={styles.todoListItem}>
      <div className={styles.itemGroup}>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          id="checkItem"
        />
        <label className={styles.customCheckBox} htmlFor="checkItem"></label>
        <span className={styles.todoItem}>
          Lorem, ipsum dolor. Lorem, ipsum dolor
        </span>
        <button className={styles.deleteItem}>X</button>
      </div>
    </li>
  );
}
```

Card component is here:

```js
import React from "react";
import styles from "./style.module.css";
import TodoItem from "../TodoItem";
function Card({ card, setCard, id }) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <header className={styles.header}>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Card title"
          defaultValue=""
          maxLength="15"
        />
      </header>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="add todo"
        className={styles.todoItemField}
      />
      <div className={styles.cardBody}>
        <ul className={styles.todoList}>
          <TodoItem />
        </ul>
      </div>
      <button className={styles.deleteCard}>Delete Card</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am using this card component like this:

```js
function Content() {
  const [card, setCard] = useState([]);
  const addCard = () => {
    setCard(
      card.concat(
        <Card
          setCard={setCard}
          card={card}
          key={card.length}
          id={Math.random() * 1000}
        />
      )
    );
  };
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      {card}
      <DefaultCard addCard={addCard} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

thank you

Comment: where is input type checkbox in the given code? mostly you'll be having same id for those causing only 1st one to be selected

Comment: sorry, editted.

Comment: if ı m using id because of ı styled checkbox. And ı used label tag for this.

Comment: Add unique names to the checkboxes and also add an onChange handler to the checkbox input. https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs -> This link shows how to work with multiple checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

An ID must be **unique** in a document.

If you create an invalid DOM with duplicate IDs then most features which make use of the ID will use the **first** one.

When you click on any label, the browser will see it is for the ID `checkItem` and trigger the **first** checkbox with that ID.

Use unique IDs.

Generally, your item will need some kind of identifier (which might map back to a database row ID or similar) so you can use that.

e.g.

```
const myId = `checkbox_${group_name}_${item_value}`.
```